# Wind direction affecting temperature,

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, home-experiment, weather

I am working on a paper for a Graduate School class and I wonder how can I create an experiment that shows how wind direction affects temperatures?  I understand the concept myself however I want to be able to show school age children how this works first hand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible setup you can use.

You've got two fans at (or on) the opposite ends of a long table. There is a bawl of ice or cold water in front of one fan and an electric heating pad or a bawl of worm water in front of the other.

[image]

You turn on one fan at a time or both fans at the same time, possibly, at different power levels, and measure the temperature of the table surface or some object placed in the middle of the table, using infrared thermometer for fast response.